# Why am I unable to print a specific div?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have an html page with four(4) different tables generated with a
while loop on page load, each table has a print button with a unique I 'd. I.e **Table1 print button id is 1,Table2 print button id is 2.** Etc.
On click of any of the print button, it 's button id value is attached to the div that wraps the table. This works fine.

The issue now is
if I select the div based on the id value clicked, it always prints out the table 1 with id value of 1 even
if table 4 print button is clicked.
This is my code
for better understanding of the issue..

```
<?php
//Sql code to get data from db omitted.

//load datas into table.
$sn =0;
while($r7 = $return7->fetch_assoc()){
$sn += 1;
echo'<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home |e-Results</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="assets/ehome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <!-- jQuery  includes-->
<script src="../../exams/assets/jquery-3.6.0/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- css-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../exams/assets/bulma/css/bulma.css">
</head>
<body>';
echo'<div id ="" class="printWrapper">
<section id="showTable" class="section">
<div id="" class="box">
<h4 class="tag is-warning is-centered"> Click on each course/Subject to view full details</h4>';

//session/year of exam value display for each table.
echo' <div id="yearDisplay" class="button is-primary">';
echo $year;
echo'</div>';

echo'<div class="table-container">
  <table id="resTable"  class="table  is-bordered is-striped is-hoverable is-fullwidth is-narrow">
    <!-- Your table content -->
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>S/N</th>
      <th>COURSE</th>
      <th>DESCRIPTION</th>
      <th>TOTAL %</th>
      <th>GRADE</th>
      <th>REMARKS </th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
 <tr>
</td>';
echo"<tr>";
echo"<td>".$sn."</td>";
echo"<td class='tag is-success'>".$r7['exam']."</td>";
echo"<td>".$r7['description']."</td>";
echo"<td>".$r7['finalScore']."</td>";
echo"<td>".$r7['grade']."</td>";
echo"<td>".$r7['remarks']."</td>";

echo"</tr>";
echo"</tbody>
  </table>";
echo"<button id='$sn'  class='button is-link is-rounded is-small block printdiv '>Print</button>";
echo'
  </div>
</section>
</div>';
}//while end.
echo'</body></html>';
?>
```

This is the JavaScript to print.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".printdiv").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $(".printWrapper").attr("id", id);

    //Below to test if the id is attached for each print button that is clicked which works fine.
    //alert($(".printWrapper").attr("id")); return; 

    //Now to print div based on the id of button clicked.
    var div = $("#" + id).html();

    //function to handle the printing.
    function printThis() { 
      var a = window.open('', '', 'height=500, width=500');
      a.document.write('<!DOCTYPE html><html>');
      a.document.write('<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="../../exams/assets/bulma/css/bulma.css">');
      a.document.write('</head>'); 
      a.document.write('<body><h1><br>');  
      a.document.write(div); 
      a.document.write('</body></html>');
      a.document.close();
      a.print();
    }
    printThis();
  });
}); //docs end.
```

The issue again is that, it always prints the table 1 even if any other button is clicked.

What am expecting for example is that, if print button on table 4 is clicked then div with id=4 should be printed. Same with Table2, table 3. Etc

Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: You're creating a duplicate ID with `$(".printWrapper").attr("id", id)`. IDs have to be unique.

Comment: document.write is not like writing a string......

Comment: `a.document.write($(this).closest("div").find("table").innerHTML)`

Comment: and `a.document.write('<body onload="window.print()"><h1><br>');` instead

Comment: so, let me get this straight ... you're sending multiple full web pages ... `<html> ... </html>` and are wondering why you have issues?

Comment: `var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $(".printWrapper").attr("id", id);` You set all the elements with the same ID WHY WHY WHY WHY WHY? Why are you setting an id?

Comment: Alternatively set all elements to class="noprint" which is display:none  and remove it from the thing you want to print. Then window.print() will print just that thing

Comment: After going through the comments, I added a unique id to all the divs id=" " class="printWrapper"> during the while looping. Then edited the JavaScript to ``` $(".printdiv").click(function (){
var id = $(this). closest ($(".printWrapper")).attr("id");
var div =$(this).closest($("#"+id)).html(); ....  ```   and it worked!!  Thanks to you all for the help!!!